# next Monday vs Monday next

Tags: word-order, alternatives

I have read for the first time the expression "Monday next". I believe that it belongs to a high register of speech and possibly it is outdated. Is that right? Is it usual somewhere ?

Comment: As far as I am aware, as a native BrE speaker, there is no difference and the two can be and are used interchangeably. Neither is outdated nor associated with a particular group of speakers. However I will concede that "Monday next" is less usual than "next Monday".

Comment: @Alan Evangelsta. The question has already been  asked and answered

Comment: **Nowhere** I could find *Monday next.*

Comment: @JagathaVLNarasimharao link? If the question was posted on EL&U that doesn't count.

Comment: Monday next is British. Both are fine. ["I read the expression "Monday next" for the first time". Where did you read it?]

Comment: I must admit that I have not heard "Monday next" even when talking to all my English friends (between 18 and 30 years old), so I infer it is less usual than "next Monday", even in UK.

Comment: @Lambie One user in a Duolingo course complained that "next <weekday>" was accepted and "<weekday> next" was rejected in a translation exercise.

Comment: "next weekday" and "weekday next" are both wrong. I am a translator and would never use either. Except: The next weekday I can meet with you is Monday, for example, yes.

Comment: I wrote "<weekday>", not "weekday". It is a placeholder for any weekday (eg Monday, Tuesday, Friday)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Next Friday" could sometimes be ambiguous.  If you say "Next Friday" on Monday 1st of September, you might mean Friday 5th of September (ie the next Friday), or Friday 12 September (ie Friday in next week)

On the other hand "Friday next" can be understood as unambiguously meaning "Friday next week" (Friday 12th September in the example).  You can unambiguously refer to the Friday 5th as "This coming Friday".

As an abbreviated form, chosen in order to be unambiguous, it sounds "clerical". It is used in contexts when short and unambiguous expressions are favoured. It does sound a little dated. Most people would prefer to use a date to avoid ambiguity and not say "Friday next". It seems likely also to be common in British or Commonwealth English, and not American English.

Answer (score 0):

As a native United States English speaker, I had a hard time finding examples of "[Day of Week] next". Almost all examples I could find were "next [Day of Week]." However, a prominent exception is the definition enacted by the US Congress (in 1844) of when the election for the offices of President and Vice President were to be held:

> the Tuesday next after the first Monday in the month of November ([source](http://memory.loc.gov/ll/llsl/005/0700/07590721.tif))

There is also a play, written by a British playwright called "Monday Next."

I don't have evidence to support this, but based on these two examples, as well as the comment by Peter Jennings on the question itself, I'd submit that it might be a Brittishism that is just not common in the United States.

Answer (score 0):

`Sunday next`and `Monday last` are not surprising phrases for me .They are still being used in India while reading the news on Radio and TV.

I have old grammar books such as 'David Green's  which have the following sentences 
They are the examples given in standard grammar books published In England.

The usage has slowly disappeared in England but has retained in India.

`1.He came here on Monday last.`✔

`2. He came here last Monday.`✔

`3.He will leave for America on Sunday next.`✔

`4.He will leave for America next Sunday.`✔

`5.He came here on Last Sunday`❌

`6.He will leave for America on next Monday.`❌

1.The rule is : The Adverbials next and Last must not follow the preposition 'On'

2.If you want to use the preposition 'on' the Adverbials next and last should come after the days such as Sunday and Monday.

3.If you do not use the preposition 'on' 
 the Adverbials next and Last precede
 the days such as Sunnday and Monday.

I here with  attach  two links  which shows that the usage *on sundaylast * and  *on monday next* are the old British Usage which has slowly disappeared In England but retained in India as is  the case with most usages

https://books.google.it/books?id=MMBgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA23&dq=%22on%20sunday%20last%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZnLu_2bTkAhUHGuwKHXFZBZ0Q6AEIUDAG#v=onepage&q=%22on%20sunday%20last%22&f=false

https://books.google.it/books?id=aA4H3PZjDXgC&pg=PA625&dq=%22on%20sunday%20next%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLsKCC27TkAhXHyqQKHe0nBcgQ6AEIVzAI#v=onepage&q=%22on%20sunday%20next%22&f=false

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I suppose it is expected that Indian media still uses those UK english expressions,since the English spoken/written there has a strong influence of England.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista.Why have you not accepted any of the answers.